# Creating a view with shadow in a Processing game

Tags: processing

I am writing a game for school project using Processing. I am currently dealing with a player's field of view. The player's field of view is basically a circle, but I would like the view to be blocked if there is an obstacle in front, meaning that you can't see the things behind the obstacle. The below image is the current results I have.

[The link to the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zu7Kz.png)

My code: http://pastie.org/10854654

The method I used is to go through every pixel in the player's field of view starting from the center, picking a path towards the circumference. As I searched outwards, if an obstacle is found on the path, I then draw a black line on the rest of the path. Changing the direction of the path degree by degree, eventually covering the whole circle.

```java
//Draw a circle field of view. 
    int[][] collisionMap = map.getCollisionMap();
    //Use a lot of small rectangle to cover the full map except of the circle field of view. 
    mainapplet.fill(0, 0, 0, 128);
    for(int i = 0; i <= MyApplet.width; i++ ){
        for(int j = 0; j <= MyApplet.height; j++ ){
            if(mainapplet.dist(playerx, playery, i, j) > FieldOfView) 
                    mainapplet.rect(i, j, 1, 1);                
        }       
    }

    //Scan the circle field of view. If there is collision , draw a line to cover the area ,which  means that the area is invisible.
    mainapplet.stroke(0, 0, 0, 128);
    mainapplet.strokeWeight(5);
    for(float i = 0; i < 360; i+=1) {
        for(float j = 0; j < FieldOfView ; j++ ){
            float x = j * mainapplet.cos( mainapplet.radians(i) ); 
            float y = j * mainapplet.sin( mainapplet.radians(i) ); 
            if(collisionMap[player.getX() + (int)x ][player.getY() + (int)y ] == 1){
                mainapplet.line(playerx + x, playery + y,
                        playerx + (FieldOfView-1)* mainapplet.cos( mainapplet.radians(i) ), 
                        playery + (FieldOfView-1)* mainapplet.sin( mainapplet.radians(i) )
                        );  
                break;
            }               
        }       
    }
```

collisionMap is a 2D array with 0s and 1s, "1" denoting that an obstacle is present at the location.

However, I find this method inefficient, therefore, causing lag. Is there a better way to do this? Or maybe there are already written tools that I can use?

Comment: The first question is: have you measured which bit is slowing it down? There are many ways this method can be improved, but to know which one to choose, you first need to figure out what is slow in the current solution.

Answer (score 0):

What you're talking about is called **2d shadow mapping**. It's not a trivial topic, but there are a ton of resources on google. I highly recommend reading up on them, because they'll explain it much better than I can.

But I did find [this sketch on OpenProcessing](http://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/29467) which does what you describe. The full code is available at that link, but the pertinent bit seems to be this function:

```java
void drawShadow() {
    PVector tmp;
    PVector m = new PVector(mouseX, mouseY); //mouse vector

    fill(0);
    stroke(0);
    for (int i=0; i < vertCnt; i++) {
      beginShape();

        PVector v1 = p[i]; //current vertex
        PVector v2 = p[i==vertCnt-1?0:i+1]; //"next" vertex
        vertex(v2.x, v2.y);
        vertex(v1.x, v1.y);

        //current shadow vertex
        tmp = PVector.sub(v1, m);
        tmp.normalize();
        tmp.mult(5000); //extend well off screen
        tmp.add(v1); //true up position
        vertex(tmp.x, tmp.y);

        //"next" shadow vertex
        tmp = PVector.sub(v2, m);
        tmp.normalize();
        tmp.mult(5000); //extend well off screen
        tmp.add(v2); //true up position
        vertex(tmp.x, tmp.y);

      endShape(CLOSE);
    }
  }
```

But honestly the best thing you can do is google "processing shadow mapping" and spend some time reading through the results. This is a huge topic that's a bit too broad for a single Stack Overflow question.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance, now I know what to search for, it really helped a lot!